# Class 'Class 'Form' not found' in fresh installation

Tags: php, laravel-6

Completely new to Laraval just extended from Magento and I'm stuck in beginning. I am running Laravel 6 on php 7.2.2 ubuntu.

When I create views below code is getting problem.

**But it gives en error because I am running Laravel 6.

Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.**

```
@foreach ($members as $member)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $member->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $member->email}}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('members.show',$member->id) }}">Show</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('members.edit',$member->id) }}">Edit</a>
            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['members.destroy', $member->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

For this I found this https://laraveldaily.com/class-form-not-found-in-laravel-5/.

Comment: make sure you already install it from this command
 `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Comment: First you need to search a bit about the laravel collectives, it's not a one day learning framework.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install `laravel collective` first from composer 
by running this command

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

for more info, you could check [Docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html)